# Xbase - How to add tags on top on inferrer generated methods

Tags: java, xtext, xbase

I have figured out how to create methods and add to the bodies of the method. What I need to also do is add annotations to the generated method such as `@Test` etc, how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to infer annotatations inside the inferrer you could do something like

```
members += greeting.toMethod("testHello" + greeting.name, typeRef(Void.TYPE)) [
    annotations += "org.junit.Test".annotationRef()
    body = '''
        // TODO
    '''
]
```